# CommandLine parameters not working in Batch files

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, default-value

I'm writing a Batch file program where I may/may not pass parameters. 
If i don't pass parameters, I want a default value to be considered.

My code is below which is not working still:

```
IF "%1"=="" (
SET iterations=100
) ELSE (
SET iterations=%1

for /l %%n in (1,1,%iterations%) do ( . . . . . .
```

Can anyone point why it's still not working?

Comment: Your closing bracket for the `ELSE` is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jeb pointed out, all that is missing is the closing parenthesis:

```
IF "%1"=="" (
     SET iterations=100
) ELSE (
     SET iterations=%1
)

for /l %%n in (1,1,%iterations%) do (
    echo %%n
)
```

This works.